# What is Agent 355's real name in "Y: the Last Man"?

Tags: dc, vertigo-comics

I have just finished "Y: the Last Man", and it is never revealed what the beloved character's name is.

Apparently the author gave hints throughout the story, but I didn't pick up on any of them. **What was her real name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artist Brian K. Vaughan indicated in an interview that there were *clues* contained in the comic regarding her true name.

> **ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY:** *We saw 355 whisper her true name into Yorick’s ear, but you didn’t share that info with the reader.*
>
> **BRIAN K. VAUGHAN:** *Would you like to know what it is?*
>
> **ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY:** *I would love to!*
>
> **BRIAN K. VAUGHAN:** *I’ll just say it’s hidden somewhere in the 60 issues. And if you really worked for it, it’s there…. I think there
>   are certain answers that the audience demands and are owed. And there
>   are certain other mysteries where whatever answer you come up with
>   will be more satisfying than anything I would give you. I think a
>   certain amount of ambiguity is what brings beauty to work — which I
>   know is scary to hear, coming from a guy who works on Lost.*

---

There are indications that her first name might be 'Peace'

- **The cover for issue #058 (making the peace symbol)**

[image]

- **This panel from issue #060 depicting Agent 355's**

> **Grave marker**
>  [image]

Answer (score 3):

I think another hint that her name is "Peace" comes during the end of the "One Small Step" story arc after Alter gets knocked out and Sadie takes command of the IDF brigade. Congresswoman Jennifer Brown is on the phone, demanding to know what's going on in regards to her son's whereabouts, and Sadie tells the radio operator that she has just one word for her..."shalom."

I think that the surprise and confusion that Congresswoman Brown expresses is supposed to draw attention to the significance of that word at that particular moment in the story. She says she doesn't understand the word in its context, although she admits that she knows that it is an expression for "hello," "goodbye," and literally means "peace."

Then again, another hint regarding her name being "peace" occurs during the ending of the "Safeword" arc, in which Yorick has his vision that convinces him not to give up on life (spoiler alert: it's Agent 355, as he reveals in issue 58), and right before he leaves 711's cabin, he says that he has spent a lot of time reading "War and Peace" while the woman who tied him up and interrogated him tells him that endings have to be earned.

Considering that 355's name (I believe) is revealed on the tree demarcating her grave underneath her number, it gives much more meaning to what Sadie says to Yorick's mother, no matter how vague that one word may be. She is essentially saying "your son is in 355's hands" and alluding to the fact that the titular last man is no longer under the wing of his mother, but of another mother-like figure, the notorious Culper Ring agent. In one of the series's many gender role reversals, it is remarkably similar to the tradition of a woman being walked down the aisle to the altar by her father and "given away" to her new husband (which is especially amusing to readers of this series, given that Yorick and Agent 355 finally admit in issue 58 that they love each other, and after she is murdered, all the flashbacks depict Yorick dealing with some sort of memory of her, as if she were his soulmate that he should have married!)

In regards to the recurrence of "shalom," given that it is a greeting and a farewell in Hebrew, keep in mind that Agent 355 reveals her true name to Yorick right as they are preparing to begin their life together as lovers instead of just friends, and as soon as this last big secret of the series is answered, Alter, who had been trailing the duo the entire time, murders 355 with a sniper's bullet to the head. In this case, it was, as awful as it sounds, perfect in the timing of these events. We find out later (from the tree) that her name is Peace (which is "shalom" in Hebrew, as we learn earlier in the series), and in that moment she was attempting to not only show Yorick how much she loved him (by revealing one of her deepest secrets to him, showing that he had earned her trust and helped her regain the life she thought that she had lost as a child), but also trying to tell him "hello." However, because of how short-lived this beautiful exchange lasted, it became a way in which she gave him a loving message of "goodbye." Hello...goodbye...Peace.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to use quote markdown, `>` at the beginning of a line, and spoiler markdown `>!` at the beginning of the line, to make it easier to tell what is what.

Answer (score -1):

It’s got to be Allison. At the end he goes to see Dr.Man and he says her can’t bear to call her Allison... which he never had an issue with previously.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] this answer to expand a bit more on this explanation, for the benefit of those of us who aren't familiar with this series? For example, who is the "he" you mentioned here? And in which specific issue did he go to see Dr. Man?